# Which form is correct: "the fruits that no one likes" or "the fruits that no one like"?

Tags: grammatical-number

Should "no one" be followed by the singular or plural form of "like"? I know that "no one" is generally followed by singular verbs, but would being preceded by a plural noun make this an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The finite verb form depends on the subject and the numerus of an object is irrelevant.

- He likes the book Hunger Games - He likes the books by Suzanne Collins.

Even if the object is in front position it has no influence on the finite verb form.

Answer (score 1):

"No one" is followed by singular verbs. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_pronoun#Table_of_indefinite_pronouns

Comment: Would being preceded by a plural noun make this an exception?

Comment: Not at all, no, they're part of two different phrases. You can invert it to make more sense out of it: "No one likes the fruit" vs "No one like the fruit"